# Is it possible to reproduce this "comics" effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, filter, halftone

I’m looking for a way to reproduce a similar effect in Photoshop. Is there a filter that can produce this?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to GD. I cannot see a font there? is it the pattern you are after?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply. Sorry, I was speaking about this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an effect called `halftone.` It is basically a raster effect, and you can play with settings in `effects` -> `halftones`. You would have to make a few different layers for different colours.

**[This post explains how it works.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20020/how-to-create-a-decreasing-stippling-or-halftone-effect)**